# Stuck in login loop (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, login

A friend tried to reinstall the graphics drivers on his Ubuntu 16.04 computer (upgraded from 14.04 some 3 or 4 months ago) and now is stuck in an endless login loop.  I have spent nearly 1.5 hours trying most of the commands proposed in multiple of the answers [in this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) and a couple others to no avail.

Here is `.xsession-errors`

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: gnome-session (Unity) main process (2094) terminated with status 1
upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
upstart: logrotate main process (1919) killed by TERM signal
upstart: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_sbin_upstart.104.crash) main process
 (1983) killed by TERM signal
upstart: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.crash) main proc
ess (1984) killed by TERM signal
upstart: bamfdaemon main process (2047) killed by TERM signal
upstart: hud main process (2061) killed by TERM signal
upstart: unity7 pre-start process (2065) terminated with status 143
upstart: indicator-bluetooth main process (2106) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-power main process (2107) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-datetime main process (2111) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-sound main process (2116) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-printers main process (2119) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-session main process (2120) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-application main process (2138) terminated with status 1
upstart: unity-panel-service main process (2098) killed by TERM signal
```

It is likely this may be an issue encountered by someone else before but, with so many other similar questions/answers, it has been hard to find something that would work.

At this point I think I would have spent less time if from the beginning I had re-installed the whole OS.

Graphics card: AMD Radeon HD 6350 512mb

Comment: What GPU are you using?

Comment: @PatrickNegus just added the details.  It is a: AMD Radeon HD 6350 512mb

Comment: And uninstalling the AMD proprietary drivers didn't work? At this point, I'm thinking you should boot a LiveCD, backup any needed files, and reinstall.

Comment: That is what we are doing now (backing things up).   Unfortunately, the backup seems to be taking too long (we are doing a backup vis SSH).  If in the meantime anyone has other ideas on what to try, I am willing to to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting Ubuntu in recovery mode.

First, Connect an ethernet cable and manually configure a network connection:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic

Make sure that you have an internet connection:

```
ping -c 4 google.com
```

From there, remove amd and nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xorg-driver-fglrx fglrx* nvidia* nouveau xserver-xorg-video-ati
```

This should remove amd and nvidia video drivers.

Install the open source video driver:

(Proprietary drivers can be installed later)

```
Intel: no action needed
AMD: sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
Nvidia: sudo apt-get install nouveau
```

Reconfigure x:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6 dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.old
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Update and fix broken dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get check
```

Now reboot:

```
sudo reboot now
```

Your system should be back up now. To install the proprietary driver or for other gpu chips, go here for instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto

Comment: I meant it as a general answer. I know, I don't know his hardware as he hasn't specified it. I came up with this as the best course of action. Asking him to remove proprietary driver, restore defaults, and cleanly re-install proprietary driver. This course of action is likely to remove and redo all configuration. Just trying to help a fellow Ubuntu user here.

Comment: Okay, I have redone the answer. I hope it is sufficient.

Comment: Yes, good answer.

Comment: Tried this... no luck.  Still the same symptoms.

Comment: By the way, the network connection is OK and has not suffered interruptions.

Comment: Try 'sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity'

Comment: Sorry, didn't make it readable enough. 'sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop &&
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity'