# Ubuntu 16.04LTS doesn't boot or gets stuck in login loop after install

Tags: boot, nvidia, graphics, login

Launching the Ubuntu install from USB works fine, I've installed along side Windows 10. after the install the OS will boot and sit on a black screen (note that I am unable to access the console here). If I lunch recovery from Grub and then simply continue, the OS will boot.

From here I updated everything (apt-get update, apt-get dist-upgrade) and tried reboot, I still get the black screen...

Back to recovery mode and boot, then I did a graphics driver update (apt-get install nvidia-current), and on restart I now have a login screen... However when I try to log in I see the screen flashes and then I'm greeted with the login screen again (note I can access console from here, but recovery mode now has this issue too).

I am able to revert back to getting the black screen but also being able to boot via recovery mode by following the instrucitons here [Stuck in login loop (Ubuntu 16.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/842640/stuck-in-login-loop-ubuntu-16-04).

All I'm looking for is to boot the OS normally.

System Specs:

```
CPU: Intel i7-4790k
GPU: NVidia GeForce GTX 750Ti
Memory: 2x8GB Crucial DDR3 @1600MHz
Storage: Kingston 240GB SSDnow V300 (all other drives unplugged)
Peripherals:
-   Logitech K120 USB Keyboard [PN:820-004515]
-   HP 5 Button USB Mouse [PN:BR376AA]
```

I'll be more than happy to post any error logs but I'm still fairly new to Linux in general and don't know everything that I'm looking for, so if you need anymore information please let me know to get it and I'll get it for you :)

Note that I've tried a number of different Linux based OS's.

- Ubuntu (black screen, or login loop)
- Debain (black screen)
- SteamOS (boots into big picture mode fine, black screen when trying to go to desktop or access the console)
- Kali (boots into desktop fine, glitches with rendering text)

To be honest I'll be happy with almost any Linux based OS provided it's easy enough to use and install programs on (the downfall of lesser common distros such as Kali for a noob user).

Thanks

REQUESTED OUTPUT > sudo lspci -nnkv | grep -iA20 vga

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0412] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [1458:d000]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at f7400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [disabled] [size=64]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: i915

00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [8086:0c0c] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [8086:2010]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f7a14000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI [8086:8c31] (rev 05) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI [1458:5007]
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
    Memory at f7a00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] [10de:1380] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] [1043:84bb]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at f7000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:0fbc] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:84bb]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at f7080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard [1458:e000]
```

Comment: have you got nomodeset in your Ubuntu grub

Comment: Reading the description of thar flag and the symptoms I imagine that it was off, I need to check it... I'll see what happens by changing it too

Comment: Okay, that's helped... Now I've booted up but the display is fixed at 640x480. I've made this grub setting permanent so I can at least get in to do things but I need to fix the resolution.

Comment: what is your output from sudo lspci -nnkv | grep -iA20 vga

Comment: I've been searching around and I've now set my grub settings to include GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080 and GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep. But I feel like this is more of a work around than a fix so I'm still hopeful on finding more information if anyone can help.

Comment: Question still open, awaiting comments / answers